# Azure IoT hub started throwing Management operation failed. status-code: 401

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-iot-hub

We have a legacy Webjob that reads messages from an IoT Hub on Azure. Since yesterday it started throwing the following error in startup, when connecting to the endpoint:

```
Management operation failed. status-code: 401. status-description: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation..
```

To connect we used the default eventHubName and a connectionsting from the Shared Access Policy:

```
HostName={our hoist here};SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey={key here}
```

It was all working fine until yesterday end of morning, when we started getting the error. Googling did not give us an real clues or solutions.

We have tried changing the receiverConnectionString to the secondary one, but to no avail. Checked all permissions for the iothubowner, but nothing changed there.

As some sort of 'let's just see if it works', after many hours of trying we tried the

```
Event Hub-compatible endpoint
```

from the Built-in endpoints section, that looks like:

```
Endpoint=sb://{prefix}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey={key here};EntityPath={path here}
```

And all of a sudden things started working?! Was there any breaking change that we may have missed here?

Some context. We are using some deprecated packages like:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 2.1.0
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus 2.1.0
- WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 6.2.2
- WindowsAzure.Storage 8.7.0
- Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost 3.1.5

Further log:

```
[12234a: INFO] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'Functions.ReceiveDataBatchAsync' was unable to start. ---> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingException: Management operation failed. status-code: 401, status-description: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation..
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpServiceClient`1.RequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpServiceClient`1.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result, MethodData md, MethodCallMessage mcm)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpServiceClient`1.AmqpClientProxy.Invoke(MethodCallMessage mcm)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.RealProxy.Invoke(Object[] args)
[12234a: INFO]    at proxy_2.EndGetRuntimeInfo[T](IAsyncResult )
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient.GetRuntimeInfoAsyncResult`1.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__12_3(GetRuntimeInfoAsyncResult`1 thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
[12234a: INFO] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient.<GetRuntimeInformationAsync>b__4_1(IAsyncResult r)
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
[12234a: INFO] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventProcessorHost.<InitializeAsync>d__53.MoveNext()
[12234a: INFO] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventProcessorHost.<StartAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
[12234a: INFO] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
[12234a: INFO]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.RecoverableException.TryRecover(TraceWriter trace, ILogger logger)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
[12234a: INFO] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.CompositeListener.<StartAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
[12234a: INFO] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.CompositeListener.<StartAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
[12234a: INFO] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ListenerFactoryListener.<StartAsyncCore>d__8.MoveNext()
[12234a: INFO] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[12234a: INFO]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.H
[12234a: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -1
[12234a: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
```